# Cron faster than script

Tags: php, cron

im wondering what would happen if a cron job is set to run every minute but the script it runs takes 2 minutes to run? Would it queue itself, ignore runs if previous cron is still running or run the same file simultaniously? Thanks!

Comment: You can check [Prevent duplicate cron jobs running](http://serverfault.com/q/82857/200076).

Comment: Why does your cron job take two minutes to run? o.0

Comment: It takes way more, its a massive script i inherited at work.. so, yea im gonna need to fix the cron

Answer (score 3):

The cron will boot up a new PHP process every minute, and they will all operate simultaneously with various terrible results (unless your script is properly guarded against such things, anyway)

After a while, either you'll constantly have a number of simultaneous requests running OR your server will crash after running out of resources, depending on whether or not the scripts start blocking each other due to trying to access restricted resources.

Either way, it probably won't be pretty and it probably won't be what you want.

Comment: Sounds horrible. Rewrite needed